# Check if the array of dictionary already has an element

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary in which I'm adding values like so...

```
    var mydictionary = ["id": "", "quantity": "","sellingPrice":""] as [String : Any]
    dictionary["id"] = product?.id
    dictionary["quantity"] = product?.quantity
    dictionary["sellingPrice"] = product?.theRate
```

And these values I added to an array like so...

```
self.arrayOfDictionary.append(mydictionary)
```

But if `arrayOfDictionary` already contains `mydictionary`, I don't want to add it. Else, I want to add it.

I'm not sure on how this can be achieved. Hope somebody can help...

Comment: Define "contains mydictionary". You mean that all the key/values are the sames? or just some? Then "concatenate" (like summing quantity)?

Comment: Couldn't get it all @Larme...would u mind suggesting it in the answer...?

Comment: I'm asking for clarification. I mean that if arrayOfDictionary contains a dict like this (in pseudo code): [id:3, quantity:5, sellingPrice:4], and the next dict to add i [id:3, quantity:8, sellingPrice:4], do you want to replace instead the dict inside arrayOfDictionary with `[id:3, quantity:13, sellingPrice:4]`? What defines "contains", a total equivalence then?

Comment: No..I don't want to replace anything...In my case its something like this...when I select a collectionview item it is shown in a tableviewcell..& the values associated with it is stored in the dictionary. when I return back & click on another collecn view item thats also shown in the tableviewcell...& this value is also stored in the dictionary. But at this point the 1st element which was already added gets added to the dictionary again...that's why I wanted to check for duplicates..

Comment: @bws as Larme mentioned, the logic lies in your definition of the same dictionary. Based on what you are saying it appears to me that in your case, two dictionaries are the same iff they both have the same exact keys and each value to the respective key is the same. Is that correct?

Comment: @Khanal the basic idea here is to add data fr. collection view items to array of dictionary. When I click on the buttons that I have on each collection view item the data on it is added to an array of dict. while at the same time showing those data in a tableviewcell. But when I navigate back from the tableview & visit the collectionview items again and click on some other collecn.view item, so as to add them to the array of dictionary as before, then the item that was added initially gets added again. This has to be somehow prevented. The id's are not responsible for this behavior..

Comment: A similar issue also persisted with images where same images were added again.That was handled like so..` if !self.arrayOfSelectedImages.contains(where: { $0.isEqual(image) }) {
                self.arrayOfSelectedImages.append(image!)
}`